# Android Map does not work when apk is not installed from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, dictionary, android-mapview

In a project, when I install the app on a handset directly through the Eclipse IDE, I can see the Map functioning perfectly.

But if I send the apk to someone through email and they install it on the device, altough the app works they are not able to see the map but only a blank grid!

We already have the MapKey in the project. For a non-market app, how can I show the map if the app is not installed through the Eclipse IDE on my system?

Comment: Is it signed?  Are you using the export option from the Android Tools menu in Eclipse?

Comment: Does the other device have their location services and networks online and working? For debugging or personal use, you can sign it without your own keys by using Google's/Android's.

Comment: @Flynn81: Yes, it is signed and I'm using the export option in Eclipse to generate the apk.

Comment: Each api key is tied to that certificate.  When you run a project in eclipse, it uses your debug keystore.  When you export it, you most likely are using a different keystore, so your maps api key is no longer valid.  Take the keystore you used to signed the exported apk and get a new api key.  You'll need to swap the map api key back and forth when you are developing and releasing your app.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @Flynn81: Thank you for the clarification. If you post your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it :)

Comment: @JaVAndroid Glad to hear it helped.  I added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each api key is tied to that certificate. When you run a project in eclipse, it uses your debug keystore. When you export it, you most likely are using a different keystore, so your maps api key is no longer valid. Take the keystore you used to signed the exported apk and get a new api key. You'll need to swap the map api key back and forth when you are developing and releasing your app. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

"When you export it, you most likely are using a different keystore, so your maps api key is no longer valid."

Not fully correct, you can Export from Eclipse and then sign map with your key.

So full algorithm is:

```
1. Export with Eclipse

2. Create key - remember path (say mypath/myawesomeapp.key)
```

then open Terminal and goto to folder with key and type in terminal

```
keytool -list -keystore myawesomeappkey.key
```

And then you get Certificate fingerprint in page https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

Answer (score 0):

Your Google Maps API key may not match the certificate you used to sign the application, since if you use different keys for signing development builds and release builds, you will need to obtain a separate Maps API key for each certificate.

Please, check this page to find out how to generate a proper API key for Google Maps API: https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup